# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+}\frac{{e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+}\frac{{e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}}{x+1}$$
I came up with this limit recently but I think it's harder than I initially thought, unless I'm doing something wrong. I tried applying L'Hospital, but I quickly noticed that in this case it's unsuccessful, as we'll always have the $\frac{0}{0}$ indeterminate form. Then I tried forming an inequality to perform squeeze theorem, and I got this:
$$\frac{2x+1}{(x+1)^{2}}\leq \frac{{e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}}{x+1} < e^{\frac{x}{x+1}}$$
where the lower bound comes from the inequality $e^x\geq x+1$. Unfortunately, the lower bound goes to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes to $-1^+$, while the upper bound goes to $0$, so this turns out to be unsuccessful as well.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: $(-1)^+$ or $-(1^+)$ ?

Comment: I believe it is $-1+0$.

Comment: Did you try expanding the numerator in a series?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg The exponent in the numerator is large near $x=-1$. What type of series are you thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - 1^ + } \frac{1}{{x + 1}}e^{\frac{x}{{x + 1}}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - 1^ + } \frac{1}{{x + 1}}e^{ 1- \frac{1}{{x + 1}}} = e\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  - 1^ + } \frac{1}{{x + 1}}e^{ - \frac{1}{{x + 1}}}  = e\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } te^{ - t} .
$$

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something, I should've thought of substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=x+1\to 0^+$. Then the limit is $$\frac{e^{\frac{t-1}{t}}}{t} = \frac{e^{1-\frac 1t}}{t}= e\cdot \frac{e^{-\frac 1t}}{t} $$ Further, let $\frac 1t = y\to \infty$: $$e\cdot ye^{-y}\to  0$$